# Xamarin.Forms: Plugin.Geofence not showing notifications

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, geofencing

I am using the  https://github.com/CrossGeeks/GeofencePlugin nuget for Xamarin Forms trying to experiment with some geofences. Everything seems to work fine, but no notifications are showed on entry/stay/exit. Tried a notifications plugin and they are sent without problems. The location seems fine and it is inside the geofence, but still nothing.

```
        CrossGeofence.Current.StartMonitoring(new GeofenceCircularRegion("My Region", 52.922603, -1.498039, 300)
        {

            //To get notified if user stays in region for at least 5 minutes
            NotifyOnStay = true,
            NotifyOnEntry = true,
            NotifyOnExit = true,
            ShowNotification = true,
            ShowEntryNotification = true,
            ShowExitNotification = true,
            ShowStayNotification = true,
            Persistent = true,
            NotificationStayMessage = "stay message!",
            NotificationEntryMessage = "entry message!",
            NotificationExitMessage = "exit message!",
            StayedInThresholdDuration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10),

        });
```

Comment: You are giving too little information, maybe you can refer to this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37162744/xamarin-crossgeofence-transitions

Comment: I'm facing similar problems. Did you find a solution?